# Request GET/POST to google-sheet

Tags: html, api, google-sheets, request, google-sheets-api

I have a mobile application that can send data (GET/POST) to the custom URL.

GET a simply add content, GET with complete query string, POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded, POST application/JSON

this is an android application Binary Eye.

I would need to send this data to google-sheets.
unfortunately I did not find any simple functional solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)

> To write to a sheet, you will need the spreadsheet ID, the range(s) in A1 notation, and the data you wish to write arranged in an appropriate request body object. For more information about spreadsheet IDs and A1 notation, see Key Concepts in the Google Sheets API.